# I travel around the city for 5 hours, am I exempted from fasting?

Tags: sunni, sawm, travelling

My job comprises of me having to travel in a car, drop at a location and walk for some minutes distributing flyers and then the car comes and drops me at another location I keep doing this for 5 hours in the morning. From what I read people who travel a distance of 80 KMs are exempted from taking fast.

Does my case fall in that condition if the total distance is around 80 kms and am continuously on the move?

Comment: It is debatable whether your work can also be considered traveling. We all move in physical space everyday, maybe you move a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

The exemption is not for a *total* distance of 80 kms within a city, but for a radius of that distance from one's city, i.e. real travel. You are permitted to break your fast once you leave your city limits starting out on a journey intending a travel outside that radius. Ibn Taymiyyah (rh) has an interesting take on this where he says it counts as travel if it is considered "travel" in the time and place of the person. In sprawling cities, 80 km is just a one-way commute to work.

Comment: In other words, unless you call yourself a traveler(see the dictionary), then the rule doesn't apply to you :-)

Answer (score -2):

Quran specifies that you CAN skip the fast if you are on [traveling](http://quran.com/2/184). The means of travel has changed dramatically over the years. It may be possible that you can travel hundreds of kilometers without feeling hungry or thirsty or you can travel a small distance and become severely dehydrated. The number mentioned is to give you an idea of how much distance traveled at THAT time might cause such condition. It is not an absolute measure.

If you feel VERY drained after your travel, you can skip it and make up for it later.

Comment: would you define "VERY" in this context? How do we know if a person was "a little drained", "drained", "a little more drained" or "very drained"?

Comment: Well, that is something each person has to decide for himself

Comment: Hmm... Strange. Basically, you are saying _"if one feels **very** drained, then she is travelling"_. Can you provide a proof for that, please? Where/who has said that a person can decide if she is drained, hence travelling and can skip fasting during Ramadan?

Comment: No. I mean that if one is traveling then he can take advantage of this ease. In verse 2:185, Allah says that the reason of allowing people to makeup for fasts missed during Ramazan is to give ease and not hardship. The two most common reasons for hardship are illness and travel. It is common in Quran that Allah mentions some criteria and its common cases and lets the people decide to other things it apply to. Some of these applications come in hadith, e.g. Related to people you can marry (4:23) or regarding inheritance (4:11). I hope i can make myself clear.

Comment: I see. But I believe the OP is aware of that option. The actual question is whether s/he is traveling or not. From that point of view, your answer seems a little misleading...

Answer (score -2):

Fasting during an exhausting travel isn't recommended.

> **Narrated Jabir bin `Abdullah:** Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) was on a journey and saw a crowd of people, and a man was being shaded (by
>   them). He asked, "What is the matter?" They said, "He (the man) is
>   fasting." The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "It is not righteousness that you fast
>   on a journey."
>
> *Reference     : Sahih al-Bukhari 1946 In-book reference   : Book 30, Hadith 53*

But if you feel strong enough, you should fast.

> **Narrated Anas bin Malik:** We used to travel with the Prophet (ﷺ) and neither did the fasting persons criticize those who were not
>   fasting, nor did those who were not fasting criticize the fasting
>   ones.
>
> *Reference     : Sahih al-Bukhari 1947 In-book reference   : Book 30, Hadith 54*